# tensorflow program getting error saying KeyError: 'enc_vocab_size'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was working on a Tensorflow program when I got an error saying
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:255] Device mapping:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jenna/PycharmProjects/ai/main.py", line 23, in <module>
model = execute.create_model(sess, False)
File "/Users/jenna/PycharmProjects/ai/execute.py", line 106, in create_model
model = seq2seq_model.Seq2SeqModel(gConfig['enc_vocab_size'], gConfig['dec_vocab_size'], _buckets,
KeyError: 'enc_vocab_size'
Device mapping: no known devices.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I could not figure out what to do to fix this The code is bellow please tell me.
[Like of code I was using](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot/master/execute.py)

Comment: It seems like `gConfig` is not populated. Could you try printing it before this error line? Also, please make a gist or show code with syntax highlighting